# Angular ui-routing issue/ ui-router extras advice?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I have came across an issue that I can't solve with ui-router in AngularJS.
It involves independent views on the same page but one view can affect the other view conditionally. Please take my code for example:

The main template (test2.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="chatApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sticky State</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="routeCtrl">

  <div ui-view><div>

  <script src="/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/0.0.13/release/ct-ui-router-extras.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/controllers/test2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test3.html

```html
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding-top:50px;">
  <button ui-sref=".public">public Chat</button>
  <button ui-sref=".friends">friends</button>
  <button ui-sref=".search">search</button>
  <div style="padding-top:50px;">
    <div ui-view></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6" style="padding-top:50px;">
  <div ui-view="chatview"></div>
</div>
```

test3.js

```js
var chatApp = angular.module("chatApp", ['ui.router','ct.ui.router.extras']);


chatApp.config(function($stateProvider, $stickyStateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

  $stateProvider


        .state('home', {
                 url: '',
                 views: {
                '': {templateUrl: 'test3.html'},
                 'chatview@home': { template: 'public chat' }
               }

             })

        .state('home.public', {
            url: '/public',
            views: {
            'chatview@home': { template: 'public chat' }
          }
        })

        .state('home.friends', {
            url: '/friends',
            views: {
            'chatview@home': { template: 'private chat' },
            '': { template: 'private' }

          }

        })

        .state('home.search', {
            url: '/search',
            template: 'search'
        })


});
```

Want I am trying to achieve:

"public chat" is a button that is suppose to take the `<div ui-view="chatview"></div>` to public chat completely non dependent on the state of the `<div ui-view></div>`. For example If I was on the friends tab and I clicked on the public button the friends state should remain while `<div ui-view="chatview"></div>` loads the public chat template . The friends button loads "private chat" but if I clicked on the search tab I don't want my private chat to leave. Yes I could changed my named view in that state to be the same template as friends but it goes back to the same issue as If I went from the public button to search button.

I hope I am making sense, here is what I need.

desired action: when on friends tab and user clicks on public button `<div ui-view="chatview"></div>` should be populated with the public chat **WHILE** the friends tab remains in its current state at `<div ui-view></div>`.

**AND**

when on search tab and user clicks on public button `<div ui-view="chatview"></div>` should be populated with the public chat **WHILE** the search remains in its current state at `<div ui-view></div>`

**AND**

when user clicks on public button (goes to public chat) then clicks on search tab while public chat state remains on `<div ui-view="chatview"></div>`.

**AND**

User is currently on private chat and clicks on search tab `<div ui-view="chatview"></div>` should stay on private chat while  `<div ui-view></div>`populates with the search template.

The conditions increase if I put in more tabs but I'm pretty sure I need ui-routers extras but I can't understand the documentation. A good example is the chat application messenger. The issue is with the url's as one URL will load its specified template not taking into consideration that I have to seperate views. A code example would be really appreciated thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you using `ui-view` from ui-router in your code but using `ng-view` from angular router in your description is a mistype?

Comment: sorry, I mistyped it! WIll change it now. Any ideas though regarding my question?

Comment: If I've understood it correctly you'd like to do something similiar like in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039342/how-to-correctly-implement-multiple-views-with-ui-router-in-angular/32041089#32041089). Have a look at my answer there and I think that should help to solve your problem.

Comment: hi, the issue in your example is that the states are still dependent on each other, for example when you go back to left1 the right reverts back while i am trying to get the left to be independent of the right but the right dependent of the left. I think my question shows it quite well.

Comment: I read your SO answer wrong but still find it hard to apply to my context